# Ubuntu - twinview - I want the desktop icons on the right monitor

Tags: ubuntu, twinview

I'm running LinuxMint (Ubuntu derivative) with TwinView enabled.

My right monitor is my primary and my left monitor is my secondary.

The problem is that the desktop icons remain on the left monitor even though the taskbars are on the right/primary monitor.

Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: good question -- i tried running Xubuntu in a dual-monitor config and had the same problem.  and the icons resisted being moved to the primary monitor.  haven't tried Gnome yet, but it sounds like i can expect similar wonkiness.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case you find no solution, you could opt to just drag them over.

Comment: heh...the problem with this is that it screws up if I disconnect the 2nd monitor (which is a laptop) and then try to work from home on the laptop only.

I'm looking for a way for it to know that the primary desktop should have the desktop icons...whatever the primary desktop is at the time.

Answer (score -2):

Tell Mint that the that the primary monitor is on the left but select the monitor you have actually positioned on the right. It takes a minute or two to get used to dragging your mouse to the right to get to the monitor on the left but it is not to bad.

NOTE: obviously this will cause many problems if you are running a program (computer game) across both monitors. If you are instead placing separate programs on each monitor (firefox on your primary and a pdf on the secondary) there will be no loss in functionality.